# Distributed JobRunr using single data source

Tags: kotlin, jobrunr

I want to create a scheduler using JobRunr that will run in two different server. This Scheduler will select data from SQL database and will call an api endpoint. How can I make sure these 2 schedulers running in 2 different server will not pick same data from database ?

Main concern is they should not call the API with duplicate data from 2 different server.

As per documentation JobRunr will push the job in the queue first, but I am wondering how one scheduler queue will know that the same data has not picked by other scheduler in different server, is they any extra locking mechanism I need to maintain ?

Answer (score 0):

JobRunr will run any job only once - the locking is already done in JobRunr itself.

Comment: Does it mean when JobRunr in one server pick data id 5, then JobRunr in other server will not pick that data id 5 to call api (considering both are using same database) ?

Comment: Yes, please read the docs: https://www.jobrunr.io/en/documentation/faq/#how-does-jobrunr-make-sure-to-only-process-a-job-once

> How does JobRunr make sure to only process a job once?
JobRunr uses optimistic locking to make sure that a job is only processed once. Concretely, this means that when a BackgroundJob server starts processing a job, it first changes the state to PROCESSING and tries to save that to the StorageProvider. If it succeeds, it means that the job is not being processed by another BackgroundJob server and the current BackgroundJob server can process it.